# How to append block to parent using jade template

Tags: node.js, inheritance, include, append, pug

I'm trying to create a modular layout using jade template. I would like to append a script block from a child into its parents parent. I'm not quite sure if its possible at all.

Here is my structure

layout.jade

head.jade

index.jade

users.jade

layout.jade:
    doctype
    html#html
        include head

```html
    body
        block content
```

head.jade:

```html
head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    block scripts
```

index.jade:

```html
extends layout

block content
    h1 Hello

    include users
```

users.jade

```html
block append scripts
    script(src='/javascripts/user.js')  

ul
    each user, i in users
        li(class=i+"-"+user) #{user}
```

My desired html output should be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/javascripts/user.js">  <!--// append this from user.jade into head.jade //-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Hello bob</h1>
        <li class="0-user1">user1</li>
```

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/864 -- looks like it's not really supported.

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible, and there are [examples in the jade documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a12) that do exactly this. Your code all looks fine except you need to indent your `script` tag in `users.jade` so it is indented below the `block append script` directive.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for your reply. Well it doesn't seem to work so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The intend got lost while copy&paste, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: More details, please. Please fix your formatting or make gists for the files. Whitespace is significant so we need accurate representations in order to help. Are you doing this in express or on the command line? What is your actual output HTML?

Comment: I did edit it. Output is as expected just the script part is missing. I'm using the commandline (supervisor app.js) 
Extending in users.jade results in inserting layout.jade twice. So its obviously wrong to extend withing a child from its parents parent.

Comment: Try `append scripts` instead of `block append scripts` ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the same approach to define a tab-control. 
I defined the pages in separate jade-files.
Each jade-file appended a block that contained the tab-page which was included. 
It also did not work until I appended something to the block in my 'index.jade' as below:

```
extends layout

append scripts
    //- dummy

block content
    h1 Hello

    include users
```

However I also would like to add that since I added multiple .jade files I ran in the following. Each file inclued jade-template used block append to add a tab-page but the order in which the pages were added was reversed.